# Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 8 and Xcode 6. I `encountered Attempting to badge the application icon problem`, and I have setup the steps in app delegate.

Did I missed something?

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
[self registerRemoteNotification];
...
}

- (void)registerRemoteNotification
{
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {

        UIUserNotificationSettings *uns = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:uns];
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType apn_type = (UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:apn_type];
    }
#else
    UIRemoteNotificationType apn_type = (UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:apn_type];
#endif
}
```

Comment: Do you receive the Message where you can either accept/decline these notifications?

Comment: I did for the first time

Comment: Well it has been a long time, but to my surprise, these requests appear once per day even if you delete/remove the app from the device, it should be noted.

Comment: If you deleting exceeds 24 hours, I will get it again. My problem is not getting the iOS asks me to allow notification